# Operation `mytables.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, backend

I am trying to save data to my database MongoDb atlas by making a post request but getting this error "**Operation `mytables.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms**". I have tried many solution  available on internet but none of them is working for me (

**Server.js**

```
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const dotenv = require('dotenv');
    const routesUrls = require('./routes/routes');
    const cors = require('cors');


    dotenv.config();

    mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_ACCESS,{ useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useCreateIndex: true},()=>console.log("Datbase Connected"));


    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(cors());
    app.use('/app',routesUrls);
    app.listen(3000,()=>{
        console.log("server.js");
    })
```

**routes.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const signUpTemplateCopy = require('../models/SignUpModels');

router.post('/signup',(req,res)=>{
    

    const signedUpUser = new signUpTemplateCopy({
        username: req.body.username,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
    })

    // res.send("Hello");
    signedUpUser.save()
    .then(data=>{
        res.send("success");
    })
    .catch(error=>{
        res.send(error.message);
    })
})

module.exports = router
```

**SignUpModels**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const signUpTemplate = new mongoose.Schema({
    
    username:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        required:true,
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },
    date:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now,
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('mytable',signUpTemplate);
```

**dot.env**

```
DATABASE_ACCESS = "mongodb+srv://nikhil:tempPass@cluster0.lqfx7.mongodb.net/mytable?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#buffering

> Mongoose lets you start using your models immediately, without waiting for mongoose to establish a connection to MongoDB.

Try

Start your application only after DB is connected.

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_ACCESS,{ useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useCreateIndex: true},(err) => {
    console.log(err);
    app.listen(3000,()=> {
        console.log("server.js");
    })
});
```